# KDE top bar in window

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde

[image]Why I can't see the top bar of a window in KDE?
I mean, I can't see the options in the window of let's say, chrome. The options like, edit, tools, archive,etc.

Comment: chrome doesn't have the menubar enables by default, check here - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TfCIsMvQTXY

Comment: So all the menus bar are now replaced with the "three bars" menu at the top right of the screen?

Comment: apart from chrome please show an example.

Comment: i edited the post (added a picture) ... thats the three bars menu that im talking about.  What other apps have that menu ? i see it in thunderbird, mozilla and chrome.

Comment: Thats the title bar buttons, every window has that

Comment: And where's the menu bar then?

Comment: Open dolphin and see if its there.

Answer (score 0):

You ask a *very specific* question about only a single application (Chrome). In your comments later, you extend your question to other *very specific* applications. This has nothing to do with KDE whatsoever.

- **Chrome** [*does not* have a menu bar](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TfCIsMvQTXY), so there's no point in searching for one.
- **Thunderbird, Firefox, Mozilla etc.** have a menu bar that you can **switch off**. (Right-click on the tab bar and select the menu "Menu bar")
- **Other applications (Dolphin)** usually *have* a menu bar

A completely different question is **why** these applications are made this way: I remember reading a comment from google engineers that they wanted to "maximize the application-space" on the screen and therefore were looking to reduce the surrounding space to the absolute minimum possible. Mozilla followed suit with that development. Web browsers were almost the only applications where this development really made it to the end user.